# Как создают сетевые протоколы?

Tags: сеть

Хотелось бы выяснить, как на свет появляются сетевые протоколы разных уровней? Где-то читал, что их не программируют, это некие спецификации. Но как тогда они работают в компьютерах? Как их создают?

Comment: Протокол - это алгоритм плюс данные. И разрабатывается так же, как любой другой алгоритм и формат данных. В зависимости от поставленных целей. Ну а без программной (или аппаратной) реализации любой алгоритм не имеет смысла. Так что в финале их всё же программируют - разработчики драйверов, прошивок, чипов...

Answer (score 2):

Создание сетевых протоколов - это настоящее искусство, место, где встречаются инженерное мастерство и творческий гений. Это как создание блюда шеф-поваром, только вместо ингредиентов мы используем биты и байты.

Сначала у нас есть идея, что мы хотим достичь с этим новым протоколом. Мы смотрим на существующие стандарты и понимаем, где есть пробелы или возможности для улучшения. Затем начинается мозговой штурм, где мы проектируем структуру сообщений, детали формата данных и даже алгоритмы, которые сделают этот протокол действительно эффективным.

После этого начинается процесс создания технических спецификаций. Это как написание рецепта для блюда. Мы описываем, как должны выглядеть данные, каким образом устройства должны обмениваться информацией и какие правила нужно соблюдать.

Затем наступает момент тестирования, где мы проверяем наш протокол на прочность. Это, как если бы шеф-повар пробовал свою еду, чтобы удостовериться, что она вкусная и безопасная для потребителя.

Если наш протокол проходит все испытания и рецензии, он становится стандартом. Он становится доступным для всех, кто хочет использовать его, и разработчики создают программные реализации для разных устройств и платформ.

И вот тогда, когда наш протокол начинает жить в мире компьютеров и сетей, обеспечивая связь и обмен данными между ними. Это как создание великого блюда, которое люди наслаждаются в ресторане, только в мире технологии.

Comment: Какая красивая чушь)

Comment: @andreymal, ну, зачем вы так? Если посмотреть, скажем, на TCP, то похоже

Comment: @avp а если посмотреть, скажем, на QUIC, то уже не очень)